# How do I add Bonjour to Qt Creator on OSX?

Tags: qt, qt-creator, bonjour, mdns

I am creating a class to do Bonjour registartion in Qt Creator on OSX. I want to add dns_sd.h to my include configuration in my .pro file which I assume is done as follows:

INCLUDEPATH += /usr/include/

My next question is where is and how do I add the proper library? I can not find a bonjour library on OSX in either the /usr/lib folder or the /usr/lib/system folder.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the information in [Apple's documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/NetServices/Articles/programming.html), it states that it requires: -

> CFNetServices, part of the CFNetwork framework in **Core Services**

So I suggest adding the CoreServices framework to the .pro file: -

```
QMAKE_LFLAGS += -F /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/
LIBS += -framework CoreServices
```